# Как запретить, добавление бота в группы?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Подскажите, как запретить пользователю добавлять моего бота, в свои группы.

Сделать проверку по id добавляющего, если пользователя пытающегося добавить бота нету в списке разрешенных, то бот не будет работать или вовсе не добавится в чужую группу.

Comment: наводку дам, а там уже кто-то другой ответит: `bot.leave_chat(chat_id)`

Comment: а user id которые могут добавлять бота в группы можно в файл на хостинге записывать, а когда бот в группу попадает, проверять user id того кто добавляет бота в группу

Answer (score 1):

```
from aiogram import types, filters

peoples = [00000001, 00000002] # id пользователей кому разрешено использовать бота в группах

@dp.message_handler(filters.ChatTypeFilter([types.ChatType.GROUP, types.ChatType.SUPERGROUP]), content_types=['new_chat_members'])
async def group_handler(msg: types.Message):
    # Проверка если бота добавил в группу НЕзнАкОМЕЦ
    if msg.new_chat_members[-1] == bot.id and msg.new_chat_members[0] not in peoples:
        # Вы можете вот так выйти из чата
        await msg.chat.leave() 
        return

    pass
```

Comment: Спасибо, ошибок нет, но в любую группу добавляется, хоть id админов прописал и добавляю, с другого аккаунта.

Comment: @Miki может надо обновить aiogram?